# How to completely remove the value store in the text box?

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext.net

```
function NewRecord() {
   var id = Ext.getCmp('input_id').clear();
   var code = Ext.getCmp('input_code').clear();
   var description = Ext.getCmp('input_description').clear();
}
```

I need to remove the value from text box, it works but code behind still gets the id. The code above i do it in js.

Comment: If the fields are in a form, try reset () method instead of clear() and reset the form. Has a resetRecord parameter that when true unbind any record set by loadRecord. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-reset

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function NewRecord() {
       var id = Ext.getCmp('input_id').remove();
       var code = Ext.getCmp('input_code').remove()
       var description = Ext.getCmp('input_description').remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Id, you can set a value for the **reference** property. In view controller, call: **this.lookupReference("refNameToTextBox")** to get reference to the textbox;

Answer (score 0):

```
function NewRecord() {
   var id = Ext.getCmp('input_id').setValue("");
   var code = Ext.getCmp('input_code').setValue("");
   var description = Ext.getCmp('input_description').setValue("");
}
```

you can clear the text value by `setValue("")`.
please try this.